# Spring jdbctemplate best way

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

The spring.xml

```
<bean id="jdbcTemp" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="portalDataSource" />
</bean>
```

In class

```
    @Repository
public class DBUtil{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6203751104015962909L;
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemp;

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("scmLogger");

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getData(String qry, Object[] pAttr){
        log.debug("DBUtil.getData() qry "+qry);
        List<Map<String, Object>> vList =  new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>(); 
        vList = jdbcTemp.queryForList(qry, pAttr);
        return vList;
    }
```

I would like to know if this "jdbcTemplate" is a singleton i.e a single instance in my application. Is this the best way to use or any other way which will be better. Please suggest.

### Regards

Adeeb

Answer (score 0):

Though i am not a Spring pro, yes this jdbcTemplate is a singleton. Every bean managed by Spring is singleton unless specified otherwise. And there is nothing wrong with this usage.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a bean in Spring, it has a singleton scope by default.

In your case, you are not defining a different scope so it's singleton.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes by default all beans in spring are `singleton` to make sure you can specify it in bean tag

```
<bean id="jdbcTemp" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="portalDataSource" />
</bean>
```

in your class you are auto wiring it, and its the best way to do it. make sure your `id` in xml and instance variable name is same, in your code its correct `jdbcTemp`